# What to use instead of UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame for swift in ios 9.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

This might be a simple question but since I'm a beginner, it is best to ask.

As the title says what should I use instead of  `UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame` since it's deprecated in 9.0.

If possible it would be great if you can provide me with a sample or example ,since I find Apples document difficult.

Currently I use the code below but I wish to change it to the new version. I would love to hear from you!

```
  let sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
  let posX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sizeRect.size.width))
  let posY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sizeRect.size.height))
  Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(posX), y: CGFloat(posY))
```

Comment: you can use UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use

```
let rect1 = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds // Returns CGRect
let rect2 = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size // Returns CGSize
```

**Swift 3+ :**

```
let rect1 = UIScreen.main.bounds // Returns CGRect
let rect2 = UIScreen.main.bounds.size // Returns CGSize
```

Answer (score 16):

I know that `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` is the recommended alternative; however, it's not the exact equivalent to `UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame`, particularly when your application does NOT occupy the whole screen, which happens with Split View and Slide Over feature on certain iPads.

In that case, this is a good alternative:
`UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.frame`. (of course `keyWindow` has to be available, that is, you did invoke `makeKeyAndVisible`)

Comment: This is THE answer. UIScreen.main.bounds does **not** work in certain situations (i.e. when you're on a phone call).

Comment: I agree this is the answer. For instance, if your app is running side to side to another app, you can do `self.window.frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.bounds` or `self.window.frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds;` for Obj-C and most of the times people call makeKeyAndVisible after that but in this case you have to do it first like Stepheneye said otherwise you will get a nil value from keyWindow.

Answer (score 2):

As of swift 3 you need to use it like this now.

```
let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
```

and for:

```
let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [`UIScreen.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617815-main) and [`UIScreen.mainScreen()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617815-mainScreen) have both been deprecated since iOS 16.

> Apple discourages the use of this symbol. Use a UIScreen instance found through context instead. For example, reference the screen that displays a view through the screen property on the window scene managing the window containing the view.

As usual the Apple document is great at telling you what not to do, but seldom give you examples of what to do. So after some searching and testing I came up with my own solution.

I created a helper class with static functions giving me access to the current scene and from there the window and screen.

This solution only works for single window apps such as iOS and will need some additional work for iPad and macOS apps.

My solution was derived from a combination of the responses in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652555/how-to-get-uiwindow-value-in-ios-14-main-file). Both answers create a `UIWindow?` variable in the main app entry.

**The First [Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656813/1416533)**

```swift
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    
    var window: UIWindow? {
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
              let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
              let window = windowSceneDelegate.window else {
            return nil
        }
        return window
    }

    [...]
}
```

**The Second [Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476042/1416533)**

```swift
@main
struct TestApp: App {

    var window: UIWindow? {
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
              let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return .init(windowScene: windowScene)
    }
}
```

I'm not in favor of the second response because it creates a new `UIWindow` from the `UIWindowScene`. You have access to an array of windows from the `UIWindowScene`.

My first attempt at this solution is to create a helper and convenience functions, and then exposing those onto `View` with convenience functions.

**Helper**

```swift
struct Application {
    public static var scene: UIScene? {
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first else {
            return nil
        }

        return scene
    }

    public static var window: UIWindow? {
        
        guard let scene = self.scene,
              let delegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
              let window = delegate.window else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return window
    }

    public static var screen: UIScreen? {
        guard let window = self.window else {
            return nil
        }

        return window.screen
    }
}
```

I chose to access to `UIScene` from the delegate instead of casting `UIScene` to `UIWindowScene` because according to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene) for `UIScene` it is:

> An object that represents one instance of your app's user interface.

Reading Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene) for `UIWindowScene` convinced me that getting it through a delegate is the more reliable way. I am curious if using a `UISceneConfiguration` entry in the info.plist is better?

**Extension**

```swift
extension View {
    var scene: UIScene? {
        return Application.scene
    }
    
    var window: UIWindow? {
        return Application.window
    }
    
    var screen: UIScreen? {
        return Application.screen
    }
}
```

I'm not a seasoned Swift developer so I am confident there is a better solution. I wonder what a better solution might be? It seems that `UIScreen.main` is an exceptionally common object it would be great to establish a new pattern for it's use.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3+:

```swift
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```