# How to get UIWindow value in iOS 14 @main file?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode12, ios14

I can able to access **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** by below implementation. But, I need **UIWindow** variable. I don't know how to get it. I'm using Xcode 12 beta. iOS14, SwiftUI lifecycle.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SSOKit_DemoApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        print("hello world!!!")
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no window at that time yet, why do you need it?

Comment: I want to integrate a sso sdk. where we need to init the sdk with the UIWindow (root View controller). Previously (swift ui 1.0) I got the UIWindow from SceneDelegate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From iOS 13 onwards, it's safe to assume that the correct way to obtain a reference to the key window is via `UIWindowSceneDelegate`.

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    
    var window: UIWindow? {
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
              let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
              let window = windowSceneDelegate.window else {
            return nil
        }
        return window
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: This will probably only work if there is only one window and one scene. That is, it will not work with multitasking on iPad or with macOS.

Comment: Awesome except of course it does not work in App::init

Answer (score 1):

iOS 14.7

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {

    var window: UIWindow? {
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
              let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return nil
        }
    
        return .init(windowScene: windowScene)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.