# SwiftUI - How to get access to "WindowScene"

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In watching the WWDC 21 videos reference StoreKit 2, there are a few functions that they reference wherein they let a value = `WindowScene` as follows:

```swift
func manageSubscriptions() async {
    if let windowScene = self.view.window?.windowScene {
        do {
            try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: windowScene)
        } catch {
            //error
        }
    }
}
```

The let line errors out with the message: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

If I try and provide more context with something like:

```swift
if let windowScene = (self.view.window?.windowScene)! as UIWindowScene {
```

I am told: `Value of type 'MyStruct' has no member 'view'`

What am I missing, must be something simple, to gain access to this needed UI element?

Thank you

***Added:***
I'd like to add that I am using a SwiftUI app that was created using a SceneDelegate and AppDelegate, not a simple struct: App, type of structure. So I am guessing I need to access something in the SceneDelegate to get the right object..

Comment: Only `UIViewController` and similar have the `view` property. Is `MyClass` a `UIViewController`?

Comment: I updated my question, I meant to say MyStruct, which is a SwiftUI view that interacts with the user and the class that implements the SK2 store..

Comment: I think I may need something like this to get access to the root scene: UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window.scene but not 100% sure on it..

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62652555/14351818

Comment: well, it doesn't quite work, but i think it gets me closer to where i am supposed to be..

Comment: Nice. What's not working?

Comment: 'UIScene?' is not convertible to 'UIWindowScene'

Comment: I can get it to run with some messing around, but this shows in the log, and its pretty cryptic, could just be beta being beta: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=911 "(null)"

Comment: Yeah you can probably ignore that

Comment: This func is “supposed” to show a sheet to manage subscriptions. But nothing shows. Ugh. They make it so simple it’s impossible.

Comment: I prob need to write out the scene and app delegate to the newer version..

Comment: "But nothing shows" yeah, I just tried and nothing showed either... you probably need to have subscriptions already set up or something

Comment: Thanks for letting me know so I’m not losing my mind there.

Comment: Got it working, it was in fact that I had a test store set up and it didn't like that.. But it worked when I turned that off and used my actual available subscriptions.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 8):

Just to provide an answer for anyone interested, with all credit to @aheze for finding it and @Matteo Pacini for the solution, to get this specific method to work when using a SwiftUI app that has an AppDelegate/SceneDelegate structure, this will work:

```
@MainActor
func manageSubscriptions() async {
    if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first {
        do {
            try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: windowScene as! UIWindowScene)
        } catch {
            //error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conversely use the view modifier `manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented:)` instead. This is Apple's recommended approach when using SwiftUI and will mitigate the need for getting a reference to the window scene.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions):

> If you’re using SwiftUI, call the manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented:)view modifier.